# UTopup.1.0.jar file Missing. Java, eclipse, Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

Problem 1 -I am using Eclipse Indigo with maven for J2EE development with Apache Tomcat. My problem is that i am able to clean project , but unable to execute *mvn install*. the screen shot shows the error message. It has the 4.6.1-RC01-SNAPSHOT but couldn't resolve to dependency. The other file *UTopup.1.0.jar* it says is missing, i searched this file on web and other team member's PC to have it in the directory, but no one has this jar file and they are running the project perfectly. The question is what is this file and from where do i get one?

Problem 2 : I got the project from SVNRepository and the project came to me *without* proper packaging, it shows the hierarchy but not the packages, any idea why is that so, Please help...

Answer (score 0):

> The other file UTopup.1.0.jar it says is missing, i searched this file on web and other team member's PC to have it in the directory, but no one has this jar file and they are running the project perfectly. The question is what is this file and from where do i get one?

Not sure about this jar myself, but can you try to remove your local repository once and and then re-attempt to *mvn install* the project?

> Problem 2 : I got the project from SVNRepository and the project came to me without proper packaging, it shows the hierarchy but not the packages

I am not sure what you mean by proper packaging, do you mean to say that eclipse isn't displaying the project in a proper structure ( like the src/main/java etc etc ). If that is the case, then simply the eclipse settings file for this particular project isn't committed on the svn. Its just a matter of setting up your classpath file so that eclipse can display the folders properly.

Comment: the repository is of around 5GB, if i remove it, i will probably be domed as there are so many things to collect. 

secondly, u tracked the issue correctly about displaying. maybe there is some other unconventional issue.

Comment: As long as everything is there on your nexus repo ( I guessed it from the download URL ), its not going to be a big issue if you remove your local m2 repo folder. Everything must have been cached in your remote nexus repo and it will get everything back. Still if you don't want to risk it, try removing the folder '~/.m2/repository/utopup' only and then try to do mvn install. If that fails, then I guess you should try removing the .m2 folder completely from your machine